# MapRoute with my extension

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, maproute

How to create right MapRoute with my extension? (e.x. "my").
This MapRoute is correct

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}.my/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

But I want use controller.my?id.
This MapRoute is wrong

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "",
    url: "{controller}.my/{tid}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", tid = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you add parameters in MapRoute, you can't simply use them as query strings.

Remove those parameters which you want to use them as query strings from MapRoute, and simply use them in action methods:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "",
    url: "{controller}.my",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

Action method:

```
public ActionResult Index(string tid) // or int tid ...
{
    // ...
}
```

So you can access that by something like `~/Home.my?tid=someThing`

Comment: thanks, but ~/Home.my?tid=someThing has 404 Response; ~/Home.my/Index?tid=someThing -  is good.

Comment: @user2666676 - I haven't any idea anymore for now... Are you sure that it's possible...?

Comment: @user2666676 Did you add the route they suggested in the answer above?  Did you make sure to add it before the default route (if you have one)?